# How to stop the program until a certain condition is met?

Tags: java, swing, timer

a question:

the main program is executed in the main thread. An object of class Timer (swing) generates an event every 30 seconds.

As a result of this, the handler of this event is launched (in a parallel thread).

I need to stop the main thread from executing while the event handler will execute.

Those. as soon as the timer handler starts executing, the main program should stop (it has a pause).

And as soon as the timer handler completes its work, the main program should continue its work.

Tell me, with what help is it more convenient and more correct to solve this problem?

Comment: *"the main program should stop"* What is it doing that needs to stop?

Comment: This means that the main thread must end the command being executed and stop (fall asleep). Until he receives the command "continue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block your Mainthread by calling: `wait()` then after your other thread finished you can call `notify()` to continue the mainthread.

Comment: in this case use wait() first, then notify() when your other thread is finished.

Comment: No. You misunderstood me.
Every 30 sec The Timer object calls the event handler.
An event handler can run indefinitely.
Only after the event handler finishes its work does the main thread need to be unlocked.
Blocking time is not known in advance

Comment: What about callbacks?

Comment: I updated my answer: you dont have to specify a time with wait(), just call notify when your other thread is finished to continue the mainthread.

Comment: I'll try to do that